# WPF Custom Datagrid with dynamic columns

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am trying to make a custom datagrid for wpf that has dynamic columns. I want all of the datagrid components creation in the custom datagrid class and fully customizable by its data source. Here is what I have now but for some reason the rows gets added but are blank.

```
public class CustomDataGrid : DataGrid
{
   public static DependencyProperty CustomSourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(CustomSource),
            typeof(ObservableCollection<CustomDataGridItem>),
            typeof(CustomDataGrid), new PropertyMetadata(DataSourcePropertyChanged));
   public ObservableCollection<CustomDataGridItem> CustomSource
   {
       get { return (ObservableCollection<CustomDataGridItem>)GetValue(CustomSourceProperty); }
       set { SetValue(CustomSourceProperty, value); }
   }

   private static void DataSourcePropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   {
       var dataGrid = sender as CustomDataGrid;

       if (dataGrid != null)
       {
           dataGrid.DataSourcePropertyChanged(e);
       }
   }

   private void DataSourcePropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   {
       int itemCount = 0;

       //Load Headers
       foreach (var customDataGridItem in CustomSource)
       {
           switch (customDataGridItem.Type)
           {
               case CustomDataGridColumnType.Text:
                   this.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn { Header = customDataGridItem.Header, Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star) });
                   break;
               case CustomDataGridColumnType.Button:
                   Columns.Add(new DataGridTemplateColumn { Header = customDataGridItem.Header, Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star) });
                   break;
               case CustomDataGridColumnType.Checkbox:
                   Columns.Add(new DataGridCheckBoxColumn { Header = customDataGridItem.Header, Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star) });
                   break;
               default:
                   break;
           }

           itemCount = itemCount < customDataGridItem.Values.Length ?
               customDataGridItem.Values.Length :
               itemCount;
       }

       //Load Rows
       for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
       {
           List<object> objList = new List<object>();

           foreach (var customDataGridItem in CustomSource)
           {
               objList.Add(customDataGridItem.Values[i]);
           }

           Items.Add(objList);
       }

   }
}
```

Here is the model class:

```
public class CustomDataGridItem
{
   public CustomDataGridColumnType Type { get; set; }
   public string Header { get; set; }
   public object[] Values { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You are adding lists to your Items collection, leaving you with a list of lists. That doesn't seem right to me. Instead of `objList.Add`, try `Items.Add`.

Comment: @SamuelMarvinAguilos: You are adding a column per item in the CustomSource? And there are different types of columns added for each item...? How many columns do you expect to end up with for starters?